# Find sum of elements within the area of 45 degree rotated rectangle

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, hashmap

- Given a matrix of integers, we'd like to consider the sum of the elements within the area of a 45° rotated rectangle.
- More formally, the area is bounded by two diagonals parallel to the main diagonal and two diagonals parallel to the secondary diagonal.
- The dimensions of the rotated rectangle are defined by the number of elements along the borders of the rectangle. Given integers a and b representing the dimensions of the rotated rectangle, and matrix (a matrix of integers), your task is to find the greatest sum of integers contained within an a x b rotated rectangle.

```
    Note: The order of the dimensions is not important - consider all a x b and b x a rectangles.
    
    matrix = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 0],
              [5, 6, 7, 8, 1],
              [3, 2, 4, 1, 4],
              [4, 3, 5, 1, 6]] 
    
    a = 2, and b = 3, the output should be rotatedRectSum(matrix, a, b) = 36.
```

I need help to understand how `range(w - 1, rows - h + 1)` and `range(0, cols - (h + w - 1) + 1)` are calculated?

```
def rotatedRectSum(matrix, a, b):
    rows, cols = len(matrix), len(matrix[0])
    maxArea = float("-inf")
    # go through possible rectangles along both diagonals
    for w, h in [(a, b), (b, a)]:
        # go through possible "anchors", which is the left top coordinate of the rectangle candidate
        for i in range(w - 1, rows - h + 1):
            for j in range(0, cols - (h + w - 1) + 1):
                area = 0
                # sum up the long diagonals
                for p in range(w): # go to next long diagonal
                    for q in range(h): # go down current diagonal
                        area += matrix[i - p + q][j + p + q]
                
                # sum up the short diagonals
                k, l = i, j + 1 # note that short diagonals have one less element than long diagonals
                for p in range(w - 1):
                    for q in range(h - 1):
                        area += matrix[k- p + q][l + p + q]
                if (area > maxArea): maxArea = area
    return maxArea
```

More Explanation: [Click Here](https://leetcode.com/discuss/interview-question/1482150/rotatedrectsum-codesignal-quora-two-sigma-oa/1638829)

Comment: *"I need help to understand the below solution"*: that is quite broad. The code already has some comments explaining particular aspects, and the discussion behind the link explains more details about why the ranges of the inner loops were chosen as they are. Can you point out what exactly is not yet clear?

Comment: @trincot need help to understand how `range(w - 1, rows - h + 1)` and `range(0, cols - (h + w - 1) + 1)` are calculated?

Answer (score 2):

> I need help to understand how `range(w - 1, rows - h + 1)` and `range(0, cols - (h + w - 1) + 1)` are calculated?

What the author calls *anchor* is the leftmost cell in the rotated rectangle that is considered. Below an orange-marked anchor and the corresponding rectangle that goes with it (width is 2, height is 3):

[image]

`i` is the row in which the anchor can be. It is clear that when the width is 2, we cannot have the anchor in the top row as we need at least one row above it to have the necessary space for the top-corner of the rectangle. As the row in which the anchor resides already counts as 1, we need `w - 1` more rows *above* it so to have enough room for the upper part of the rotated rectangle. This explains why the first `range` starts with `w - 1`. It means that the anchor cannot be in the first `w - 1` rows, and the least possible row where the anchor can be placed is the one with index `w - 1`.

With a similar reasoning we can deduce how many rows there should at least be *below* the anchor's row. There should be at least `h - 1` rows below it, so to have enough room for the bottom part of the rotated rectangle. This means the greatest possible row index for the anchor's row is `rows - h`. That means we should have a `range(w - 1, rows - h + 1)` to iterate all possible row indices for the anchor (remember that the second value given to `range` is not included in the values it yields).

The reasoning for the *second* range is the same, but now it concerns the *columns* where the anchor could possibly be (i.e. the value for `j`). The anchor can always be in the very first column, as there is no part of the rectangle that comes at the left of it. So that means that valid column numbers for the anchor start at column index 0, hence `range(0, ...)`

Finally, the number of columns that follows *after* the anchor's column is `w - 1` (for reaching the column with the top peek of the rectangle) and another `h - 1` (for reaching from there on the right most cell in the rectangle). So that gives a total of `w + h - 2` columns that need to be available at the right of the anchor's column. This means the last possible column index for an anchor is `cols - (w + h - 1)`, and so the range for possible column indices should be defined as `range(0, cols - (w + h - 1) + 1)`.

I hope this clarifies it.

Answer (score -1):

```
def rotatedRectSum(matrix, a, b):
rows, cols = len(matrix), len(matrix[0])
maxArea = float("-inf")
# go through possible rectangles along both diagonals
for w, h in [(a, b), (b, a)]:
    # go through possible "anchors", which is the left top coordinate of the rectangle candidate
    for i in range(w - 1, rows - h + 1):
        for j in range(0, cols - (h + w - 1) + 1):
            area = 0
            # sum up the long diagonals
            for p in range(w): # go to next long diagonal
                for q in range(h): # go down current diagonal
                    # print(matrix[i - p + q][j + p + q])
                    area += matrix[i - p + q][j + p + q]
            
            # sum up the short diagonals
            k, l = i, j + 1 # note that short diagonals have one less element than long diagonals
            for p in range(w - 1):
                for q in range(h - 1):
                    area += matrix[k- p + q][l + p + q]
            if (area > maxArea): maxArea = area
return maxArea
```